# If condition is not being executed in for loop of batch file

Tags: batch-file

We are calling msbuild command in batch files.

We have passed the parameters via for loop of batch file.

```
FOR %%C in (
    CommonInfrastructure
    CommonUtilities
    ) do ( 
        msbuild /t:%BuildCmdType% %BuildFile%  /p:Group=%%C %msbuildLogger% /p:Configuration=Release
        if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
        msbuild /t:SendFailureMail /p:ErrorLogFileName=%ErrorLog% %BuildFile%
        set ErrorBuild=1
        )
    )
```

When i analyzing the log file, I am seeing that code in If block is not being executed.

Due to that notification mails are not being sent.

How to make it to execute if condition ?

Comment: What is the value of system variable ERRORLEVEL?

Comment: @Vincenzo Maggio: It will be other than 0 if the msbuild fails. It is working fine if i take out of for loop and run one by one

Comment: Have you tried to set the variable to 0 before the whole program execution?

Comment: @Vincenzo Maggio I think ErrorLevel is exception variable which will be thrown away by batch file. We do not need to set.

Comment: Have you tried to debug printing the ERRORLEVEL variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jeb correctly diagnosed your problem and provided a good solution. You have other options.

`IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ...` (without percents) checks if the ERRORLEVEL is greater than or equal to 1. That should work as long as msbuild never returns a negative ERRORLEVEL.

```
FOR %%C in (
    CommonInfrastructure
    CommonUtilities
) do ( 
    msbuild /t:%BuildCmdType% %BuildFile%  /p:Group=%%C %msbuildLogger% /p:Configuration=Release
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        msbuild /t:SendFailureMail /p:ErrorLogFileName=%ErrorLog% %BuildFile%
        set ErrorBuild=1
    )
)
```

You can test for any non-zero value without using expansion by use of a variable and IF (NOT) DEFINED

```
set "success="
FOR %%C in (
    CommonInfrastructure
    CommonUtilities
) do ( 
    msbuild /t:%BuildCmdType% %BuildFile%  /p:Group=%%C %msbuildLogger% /p:Configuration=Release
    if errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 set success=1
    if not defined success (
        msbuild /t:SendFailureMail /p:ErrorLogFileName=%ErrorLog% %BuildFile%
        set ErrorBuild=1
    )
)
```

My preferred solution is to use the `||` operator to conditionally execute commands only if the prior command failed. (Note - there is also the `&&` operator to conditionally execute upon success)

```
FOR %%C in (
    CommonInfrastructure
    CommonUtilities
) do ( 
    msbuild /t:%BuildCmdType% %BuildFile%  /p:Group=%%C %msbuildLogger% /p:Configuration=Release || (
        msbuild /t:SendFailureMail /p:ErrorLogFileName=%ErrorLog% %BuildFile%
        set ErrorBuild=1
    )
)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's the type of parsing of batch files.
All percents in a block, anything inside parenthesis, is expanded at parse time not at execution time.
So your %errrorlevel% will be expanded excactly one time, before any command runs in your block. So it will *normally* always be zero.

To avoid this, there exists the delayed expannsion, use this instead.

`!errorlevel!` instead of `%errorlevvel%`
And you need to activate it before you can use it (best in the second line of your batch script).

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```