# If statement ( was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I have a bundled if statement that checks whether java is installed and whether or not i'm at college or at home it is part of a larger piece of code but doesn't work on its own either any help would be much appreciated

Triple Checked i have the right number of brackets and equals signs and making sure no obvious mistakes were made so i'm confused as to what has gone wrong

```
if exist 'C:\Temporary Workspace' (set installtype=College)
where java >nul 2>nul
pause
if %errorlevel%==1 (
    if %installtype%==College (
    goto :college
    ) else (
        set /P javaboolean=Java was not found is java installed? (Y/N)
        if %javaboolean%==Y (
            echo Please enter the path to java.exe
            set /P javalocation=e.g. C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
        ) 
    )
)
pause
exit
:college
echo success for college detection
pause
```

The error message and run time:

```
D:\Batch Testing>echo Checking Location...
Checking Location...

D:\Batch Testing>if exist 'C:\Temporary Workspace' (set installtype=College)

D:\Batch Testing>where java  1>nul 2>nul

D:\Batch Testing>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
( was unexpected at this time.
```

**I expect the output to be 'success for college detection' as the directory does exist**

Comment: @Lucas, cmd.exe doesn't use single quotes like in others, it uses doublequotes, so change `if exist 'C:\Temporary Workspace' (` to `If Exist "C:\Temporary Workspace\" (`. It has also been a while since I played with Windows, so I cannot recall if `Pause` will reset the errorlevel, you may wish to test it without the first `pause` just to check.

Comment: In your `set /P` command line quote the prompt text like `set /P javaboolean="Java was not found is java installed? (Y/N)"`, because otherwise the closing `)` might cause trouble...

Comment: @aschipfl I'm afraid that will not do what u think it will it'll simply echo the speech marks as well and that will not solve the problem as I have tried removing them before to no avail also this is NOT A DUPLICATE please remove the duplicate tag as that is 1 not the same problem and 2 that solution wouldn't even work here please check before marking it as a duplicate next time!

Comment: Well, `set /P VAR="Text: "` will not echo the `""`, but the `""` protect the parentheses in `(Y/N)` from being recognised by the parser, so the `""` definitely solve one problem. The linked threads illustrate how to fix the other issues: missing quotation in `if` condition, and lack of delayed expansion. So I disagree, this is a duplicate. And there are already a lot of posts dealing with exactly the same problems. By the way, `if exist 'C:\Temporary Workspace'` should actually read `if exist "C:\Temporary Workspace"`...

Comment: @aschipfl literally run the command ```set /P VAR="Text: "``` and you'll see that it DOES in fact include the speech marks and you stating it should be speech marks in stead of quotation marks for ```if exist 'C:\Temporary Workspace'``` will cause it to throw a directory not found error as the syntax for that command states that it should be with quotation marks.

Comment: What Windows version are you using?? Alternative way: `set /P "VAR=Text: "`. What are »speech marks«? The quotation mark `"` is used by Windows Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`), but the apostrope `'` is just an ordinary character...

Comment: @aschipfl using ```"``` will cause the location to be not recognised when talking about the ```if exist``` statement also if you run ```set /P "VAR=Text: "``` you will get an error if you run what you previously suggested which was ```set /P VAR="Text: "``` the ```"``` marks will be shown as it doesn't work the same way as the question you marked as a duplicate and if you don't believe me you may run the command yourself.

Comment: Well, I did run the commands myself; how about you? did you try to enter them into a new command prompt window (not in a batch file)? Anyway, let me repeat my question: **What Windows version are you using?**

Comment: Windows 10 but that shouldn't matter and I'm guessing by running the command you discovered that it does include the ```"``` marks when attempting to run ```set /P VAR="Text: "```

Comment: I decided to reopen the question as the major problems were perhaps not obvious enough in the linked duplicates and to provide a set-by-step answer -- I hope it helps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change your `if`s a little bit

the first could be changed to

```
if exist "C:\Temporary Workspace" set installtype=College
```

note that the single apostrophe is not a valid quotation mark in windows cmd. And you can remove your parentheses because they are not needed.

the second could be written as

```
if errorlevel 1 (
```

because `errorlevel` is not `%errorlevel%` (for a detailed explanation, read https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743 )

and the last could be

```
if .%installtype%==.College (
```

because when `installtype` is blank the `if` instruction makes no sense and produces syntax error; inserting the two `.` avoids it.

*... and, as a bonus, you might want to consider to use `if /i` to ignore case when comparing, so `College`, `college`, `COLLEGE` or even `cOllegE` would match.*

Comment: Thank you i didn't realise that you use ```if /i``` however the variable installtype does contain a value as that folder is found on my pc

Comment: sorry but that's not what appears in the output you have posted in your question. I quote: `if ==College (`

Comment: Yeah it is a little weird as the error occurs before that line of code is run yet that line of code seems to appear in the output I will remove it to prevent others from getting confused

Comment: I have edited my answer to cope with the first `if` too.

Comment: Do not use `if .%installtype%==.College (` but use `if "%installtype%"=="College" (` instead, so special characters like spaces or `&` are protected too...

Comment: I have edited my answer again to fix the first `if` too

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several issues in your code. The line

```cmd
if exist 'C:\Temporary Workspace' (set installtype=College)
```

will never set the variable `installtype`, because this checks whether `'C:\Temporary` exists, which does not, since the apostrope `'` is just an ordinary character for the Windows Command Prompt `cmd`. To make it work you must use quotation marks `"`:

```cmd
if exist "C:\Temporary Workspace\" (set "installtype=College")
```

The trailing `\` lets the condition check for existence of a directory called `Temporary Workspace` but not for a file with that name.

Note that I used the quoted `set` syntax here, which is generally recommended as it protects special characters.

---

The condition

```cmd
    if %installtype%==College (
```

will return a syntax error, because the variable `installtype` has not been set before (due to the wrong syntax you used). To avoid trouble with empty variables, quote both comparison expressions:

```cmd
    if "%installtype%"=="College" (
```

This is also described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18536743).

---

The command

```cmd
        set /P javaboolean=Java was not found is java installed? (Y/N)
```

will fail when in a parenthesised block of code, because the `)` will unintentionally be recognised by `cmd` and close the block at an undesired position. Again use quotation to solve that:

```cmd
        set /P javaboolean="Java was not found is java installed? (Y/N)"
```

or:

```cmd
        set /P "javaboolean=Java was not found is java installed? (Y/N)"
```

---

However, the condition

```cmd
        if %javaboolean%==Y (
```

will still fail, because the queried variable `javaboolean` is set in the same block of code, so the returned value is the one present when the entire block is parsed, which is an empty string most probably. To overcome this, you must apply [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Put this somewhere before to enable delayed expansion:

```cmd
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Then replace the `%`-signs by exclamation marks `!` (as you can see I again applied quotation here):

```cmd
        if "!javaboolean!"=="Y" (
```

Then put this somewhere after to end the environment localisation introduced by `setlocal`:

```cmd
        endlocal
```

Regard that all environment changes (variables, current directories) after `setlocal` are lost after `endlocal` and the state before `setlocal` becomes restored.

A similar problem is also described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12928567) and solved by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12929819).

---

Instead of `set /P` just for a Yes/No decision consider to use the [`choice` command](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html), which does not allow to enter anything else:

```cmd
rem /* The default choices are `Y` and `N`;
rem    `choice` sets `ErrorLevel` to `1` when pressing `Y` and to `2` when pressing `N`: */
choice /M "Java was not found is java installed"
rem // The following means: if ErrorLevel >= 1 and if ErrorLevel < 2:
if ErrorLevel 1 if not ErrorLevel 2 (echo Yes has been chosen.)
```

---

Instead of

```cmd
exit
```

you should use

```cmd
exit /B
```

to only terminate the batch script but keep the hosting `cmd` instance alive. This is particularly helpful when you execute the batch file from a Command Prompt window rather than by double-clicking its icon in Explorer as you can view the console output then.

---

Instead of the string comparison

```cmd
if %errorlevel%==1 (
```

you could also do true numeric comparison like

```cmd
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
```

or, if you are fine with the condition to be true if [`ErrorLevel`](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) is also greater than one,

```cmd
if ErrorLevel 1 (
```

Alternatively, you could even use [condition execution operators](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), which query the [exit code](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html):

```cmd
where java > nul 2>&1 && (
    rem // The code here is executed when `where` succeeds.
) || (
    rem // The code here is executed when `where` fails.
)
```

---

So finally, here is the fixed script:

1. Code based on yours:

   ```cmd
   if exist "C:\Temporary Workspace\" (set "installtype=College")
   where java > nul 2>&1
   pause
   if ErrorLevel 1 (
       if "%installtype%"=="College" (
           goto :college
       ) else (
           set /P javaboolean="Java was not found is java installed? (Y/N) "
           setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
           if "!javaboolean!"=="Y" (
               endlocal
               echo Please enter the path to java.exe
               set /P javalocation="e.g. C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe "
           ) else endlocal
       )
   )
   pause
   exit /B

   :college
   echo success for college detection
   pause
   ```
2. Variant using conditional execution (`||`) and the `choice` command:

   ```cmd
   if exist "C:\Temporary Workspace\" (set "installtype=College")
   where java > nul 2>&1 || (
       if "%installtype%"=="College" (
           goto :college
       ) else (
           choice /M "Java was not found is java installed"
           if ErrorLevel 1 if not ErrorLevel 2 (
               echo Please enter the path to java.exe
               set /P javalocation="e.g. C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe "
           )
       )
   )
   pause
   exit /B

   :college
   echo success for college detection
   pause
   ```

Comment: I love how u make this massive reply to try and argue back but u literally talk about how to set installtype and that it should be in ```"``` marks but then literally in the next section you say installtype wasn't set a variable 